# How To Change ng-class Based On Window (Re)Size And On Array Length

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, resize, indexof

please help me with the following.

My html:

```
<div id="button1" ng-hide="videopagepanel.indexOf('l') >= 0" class="col-md-1">
    <a ng-click="videopagepanel = videopagepanel + 'l';" ></a>
</div>

<div id="button2" ng-show="videopagepanel.indexOf('l') >= 0" class="col-md-3">        
    <a ng-click="videopagepanel = videopagepanel.indexOf('l') >= 0?videopagepanel.replace('l', ''):'l' + videopagepanel"></a>
</div>


<div id="page-content" ng-class="'col-md-' + (colnrpagecont - videopagepanel.length)">
    Some content
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function ($window) {

    if ($window.innerWidth < 992) {
        $scope.videopagepanel = 'lr';
    }  

    else if ($window.innerWidth < 1200) { 
        $scope.videopagepanel = $scope.videopagepanel.replace('r', '');
        $scope.colnrpagecont =$scope.videopagepanel.length===1?10:11;

    } 

});
```

If I have **resized** the window to for instance 1100px, the initial state is that #button2 shows up with col-md-3 and #page-content div has column size col-md-9. If I from this state click #button2, it disappears and #button1 shows up with col-md-1. The problem is that #page-content column does not adjust to col-md-11.

What is going wrong? It seems that angular does not push the update to the jQuery condition(s) or scope.

Thanks a lot for your help as I have been struggling days and hours for this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Use `window` or `$(window)` instead of `$window` (which i believe is undefined).

Also, for performance issue it is better to do

```
$scope.videopagepanel = "l";
```

instead of

```
$scope.videopagepanel = $scope.videopagepanel.replace('r', '');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: I believe ng-class will not re-evaluate by itself again. Try $scope.$apply() after modifying $scope.videopagepanel.

Comment: Where should I place $scope.$apply()?